# regexp: match only separate numbers inside specified symbols

Tags: java, regex

I am using regular expression in java and can not figure out how to match only numbers inside predefined symbols.

here is example of one of my string:

```
some text [1] some and numbers 12, 14 and more text [11,1] another text [3,6, 7] and some more text [5;16]
```

Is it really possible to retrieve only numbers in square brackets? in this case: 1 11 1 3 6 7 5 16
This should not match any other symbols in square brackets.

I have already tried several options, including:

```
Pattern k = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]");
```

But this only gives works for one number and not others. I have tried to group them, like `(?:\\[) some code inside (?:\\])` without any success.

**Update**

Workaround with grouping: 
`Pattern k = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)(?:.)?(\\d+)?\\]");` 
But produces the brackets and commas as output.

Comment: is it `[3,6, 7]` or `[3,6,7]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select those numbers, you can use the following regex:

```
(?:\G|\[)[,;\s]*(\d+)
```

It only selects the numbers.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/usznf3/2)

#### Explanation

- `(?:\G|\[)` matches the end position of the previous match **or** an opening bracket
- `[,;\s]*` matches a comma, a semicolon or a space zero or multiple times
- `(\d+)` captures the numbers

You'll have the numbers in the group 1.

Comment: Hmm, are \G and \K working with Pattern class in Java? Have tried: `(?:G|\\[)[,;\\s]*K\\d+`  and with \\G \\K

Comment: `\G` should do, but `\K` is not included in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true). Didn't check it explicitely though.

Comment: You're right, it isn't supported. I've updated my answer. cc @Vitaliy

Comment: matcher.group(1) gives only numbers. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a different workaround that might come in handy when it gets even more complicated:

A much simplier way to achieve your goal is to separate the matching into two stages. First, match the bracket's occurences with

```
Pattern areas = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
```

which will result in `[1]` `[11,1]` `[3,6, 7]` `[5;16]`.

Then for any of these use something like

```
Pattern numbers = Pattern.compile("\d+");
```

to match the actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one will help you.

Try it:

```
 Pattern k = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)(;?)(\\d+)\\]");
```